# Dispatch Livewire item not showing in debug bar

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I'm a newbie for using Laravel Livewire 3. I'm doing a project but kinda confused with the dispatch. I've read the documentation, but I still don't get it.

Actually I want every single item that I clicked in my multiple select will show in the laravel debug bar. But after 2 hours of browsing and reading the documentation I still cannot make it.

Below is my file:
CreateProduct.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Product;

use App\Models\Brand;
use App\Models\Kategori;
use Livewire\Component;

class CreateProduct extends Component
{
    public $kategoriProduk = [];
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.product.create-product', [
            'kategori' => Kategori::all(),
            'brand' => Brand::all(),
        ]);
    }
    public function add()
    {
    }
}
```

create-product.blade.php:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group" id="kategori-produk">
                    <label>Category</label>
                    <select class="selectpicker m-b-10 select2-multiple form-control p-b-0 p-t-0" multiple
                        data-placeholder="Choose category" data-live-search="true" wire:model="kategoriProduk">
                        @foreach ($kategori as $item)
                            <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->nama }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

script in my layout:

```
        @script
            <script>
                function waitForElm(selector) {
                    return new Promise(resolve => {
                        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                            return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
                        }
                        const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
                            if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                                observer.disconnect();
                                resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
                            }
                        });
                        observer.observe(document.body, {
                            childList: true,
                            subtree: true
                        });
                    });
                }
            </script>
            <script>
                waitForElm('#kategori-produk > div > div > ul > li').then((elm) => {
                    const itemKategoriProduk = document.querySelectorAll('#kategori-produk > div > div > ul > li');
                    if (itemKategoriProduk) {
                        itemKategoriProduk.forEach((item) => {
                            item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                                const clickedLi = e.target.closest('li');
                                if (clickedLi) {
                                    clickedLi.classList.toggle('selected');
                                    // const selectedElements = document.querySelectorAll(
                                    //     '#kategori-produk > div > div > ul > li.selected');
                                    const selectedValues = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(
                                        '#kategori-produk > div > div > ul > li.selected'
                                    )).map(li => li.textContent.trim());

                                    console.log(selectedValues);
                                    Livewire.dispatch("updateKategoriProduk", selectedValues);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            </script>
        @endscript
    @endif
    @livewireScriptConfig
    @livewireScripts
```

laravel debug bar after I clicked on the item:

[image: debug bar]

I'm expecting whenever I select in my multiple select, it will be updated the value in my debug bar.